# Creating a Windows security popup

Tags: windows, security, cmd

I'm using a batch file to map local drive A: to another network location. The batch file prompts the user for a username, followed by a password.

How would I implement the same functionality in a popup UI instead of relying on the console? The console doesn't provide any feedback during password entry. I want something like this picture:

[image: popup]

A UI would be more convenient for the users because they wouldn't have to retype the entirety of our standard fifteen character passwords if they've made a mistake.

Comment: To increase the likelihood of getting a helpful answer, please see [Creating a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Embedded image, condensed and streamlined language, corrected typos/spelling errors.

Comment: There's no mechanism for accessing the credentials dialog from a batch file, and even if you could you wouldn't be able to retrieve the username and password from it. If you want a real UI, stop using batch files and write an actual application.

Comment: CredUIPromptForCredentials() Will give you the password challenge you are looking for. It is part of the WindowsAPI. Not sure how you get the winapi to play with batch, but maybe this will do it: http://betanews.com/2011/07/13/take-control-of-batch-files-with-winapiexec/  Honestly, move to another programming language if your looking for a UI. Batch is a scripting language, and not really engineered for this sort of task.